GitHub Copilot responds to 'Hey Code' but dictation doesn't work
As the title explains, I can start an inline chat session using the 'hey code' voice command in VS Code, but it doesn't pick up what I say afterward.
Dictation (CTRL+ALT+V) doesn't work either.
The mic icon is grayed out, indicating that is activated, but nothing happens when I talk. This used to work just fine.

I have checked the logs and no errors are being reported.
Any ideas what may be going on?

what version were you on when you asked this?

I didn't check... but since I update all extensions automatically, I'm sure it must have been the previous one 0.21 (2024-10-02)

Well, today MS released a new version of the GitHub Copilot Chat extension (v0.22.1) which seems to have fixed the problem.
